# openSUSE - How to automatically start service on boot?

Tags: linux, opensuse

If I reboot my server then mysql service does not start automatically.

How can I remove/add services to start on boot?

Comment: `systemctl enable mysql.service` or `systemctl disable mysql.service`

Comment: I get `Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on linked unit file mysql.service`

Comment: `systemctl enable mariadb.service` worked though. Answer found here: https://serverfault.com/a/946168/470060